# Why this script keeps looping?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I wrote a shell script to listen to music (on a mac using el capitan), but encountered some problem.
The codes are:

```
#!/bin/sh
KEYF="true";
while [ "$KEYF" == "true" ] ;
    KEYS="true";
    do echo "Pick a song:\n" ; 
    select SONG in Music_Path/* ;
        do echo "You chose to listen to ${SONG}" ;
        break;
        done;
    while [ "$KEYS" == "true" ];
        do mpv "${SONG}" ; 
        echo "Do you want to repeat this song; if so, enter true; if not, enter false.";
        select KEYS in "true" "false"; 
            do echo "You picked $KEYS"; 
            break; 
            done ; 
    done ;
    echo "Do you want to pick a new song; if so, enter true; if not, enter false.";
    select KEYF in "true" "false";
        do echo "You picked $KEYF";
        break;
        done;
done
```

Everything works fine except that, after I picked false for both `KEYF` and `KEYS`, the process loops back and asks me to pick a song again. Isn't the first `while` loop there to stop this behavior?
Sincere thanks for any help.

---

**Edit:**
According to @123's comment, the problem is that `KEYS="true";` comes between the first while and `do`.

Comment: Why is `KEYS="true";` between the start of the `while` and `do` ? Infact why are there `do`s before every echo, what do you think `do` does ?

Comment: I think `do` follows such a loop as `while` or `select`; in this script, most `do`'s are followed by an `echo` because I use `echo` to tell me what the process is doing. And thanks, I correct the order of the first `do` and now it works. If you don't mind, could you explain, in an answer maybe, what problem the mis-order of `do` causes so that the loop repeats without ends? Thanks! :)

Comment: Regarding the first do, everything between while and do is executed every loop and evaluated, `KEYS="true";` is always true so the loop ran forever.

Comment: I see: the use of `do` controls what is always kept in a loop, and what comes after it is executed every loop, but refreshes each loop. Also, I learned the select construct in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/select-loop.htm); I don't know if the syntaxes are correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The select was correct, i had got it confused with case. I removed that part of my comment. And no problem glad it's sorted!